# Has Action behaviour changed between 1.7.4 and 1.8.0?

Tags: qgis, actions

I have an Action that loads raster layers (.jp2) into the current QGIS window.  This action has been working great in version 1.7.4.  I have now upgraded to 1.8.0 for many reasons, but the same Action is not working.  Here is the Action I have been using: `qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("E:\\Projects\\CityTBay\\Imagery\\2008\\%image")`

The Action will load an ortho image from the path location specified.  The image name is saved in the filed image.  When I use this Action in 1.8.0 the following error occurs:
`E:\Projects\CityTBay\Imagery\2008\%image is not a valid or recognized raster data source.`

The Action is using the Python option.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you paste the exact code you are using in the action? Have you remembered to use \\ in python for paths?

Comment: Nathan, here is the code: qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("E:\\Projects\\CityTBay\\Imagery\\2008\\%image")    using the Python option.

Comment: I have tried this on a few other computers and the following error has come back:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out what the difference is.  As of 1.8.0 the inserting of a value from a file adds the following (using Image as the field name):   [% "Image" %]

So my original Action would now read like this:

("E:\Projects\CityTBay\Imagery\2008\[% "Image" %]")

Hopes this removes some frustration for future users.

Comment: hmm I didn't think we made that change until after 1.8, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding one of the rasters directly? Any chance it's a format that is not supported in the new version? (like .ecw that requires .dlls in the right spot?)

Comment: Yes I did and it loaded fine. I have also tried it on three different computers with the same results.